# How do I determine the position of the nth most significand bit set in a 64-bit value?

Tags: java, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'm using some long values as bitmaps in a Java program. Here's my method so far:

```
public class BitmapUtil
{
    private static final long _B_MASK_LEFT_ON = 0x8000000000000000L;

    public static long setNthMsb(int n)
    {
        return BitmapUtil._B_MASK_LEFT_ON >>> n;
    }

    public static boolean isNthMsbSet(long b, int n)
    {
        return (b & (BitmapUtil.setNthMsb(n))) != 0L;
    }

    public static int getNthMsbPosition(long b, int n)
    {
        int ix = 0;
        while (ix < 64 && n >= 0) {
            if (BitmapUtil.isNthMsbSet(b, ix)) {
                if (n == 0) {
                    return ix;
                } else {
                    n--;
                }
            }
            ix++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've seen so many clever bit tricks that I can't help but feeling that there should be a better way. Is there?

Comment: "ixNthMsbSetPos"? "fIsNthMsbSet"? ... please excuse me while I throw up :-)

Comment: @Stephen C - Well I'm so used to our Hungarian that I didn't think there was anything wrong with the method names. Maybe it's more friendly on the eyes now? ;-)

Comment: It's not just the Hungarian, it's the unreadable naming. Why not use signatures like `boolean isSet(long number, int bitIndex)`. It's pretty clear a method like that returns whether the `bitIndex`'th bit in `number` is set, isn't it?

Comment: @Joren - Thanks for the feedback, I really appreciate! A lot of being readable or unreadable has to do with what you're used to and what context you find something in, though. For example, in manipulating bit patterns, I often hit the question "do I count from left or right?", so that would be someting I miss in `isSet(... bitIndex)`. OTOH, using Hungarian all the time, a signature of `ix(b, n)` would already tell me the basic operation, because I know what happens if I make `b` and `n` into `ix`. It's a lot like dialects: The Swiss speak impossible German, but they all understand it.

Comment: I don't doubt that *you* understand what the names mean. :)

Comment: @Joren - yes, I know. :) But I was trying to be a bit more general. It has to be the *group* of people working on (or potentially working on) the code who understands it. For example, a Spanish team might choose to name everything Spanish and there would be nothing wrong with that until somebody has to understand the code who is not a native speaker. I guess that's very rare, but just as there is no universal natural language, there's no naming convention that's inherently better than all others. Feedback like yours then is important to judge how specific your local dialect actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want, no clues about efficiency of it all.

```
//      long val = 0xAF00000000000000L;
        long val = 0x0000000000000001L;
        int n = 2;
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 65 && count < n) {
            if ((val & 0x8000000000000000L) != 0) {
                count++;
            }
            val = val << 1;
            i++;
        }
```

This seems to count from the left, where the MSB is position 1 and LSB is position 64. If i==65, then n bits were not set.

Comment: At least that's better than my solution because it does a lot less bit shifts. (64 instead of 64 + 63 + ... + 1) It's also a little better to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of different fast algorithms: [bit hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), look for calculating the log 2 of the number.

The most beautiful is this one, but it only works for 32 bit numbers:

```
unsigned int v; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;          // result goes here

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v = (v >> 1) + 1;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x077CB531U) >> 27];
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand this, but it certainly looks intriguing, +1. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found this in C++ for 32 bits, which could be easily adapted to Java & 64 bits

http://lsjandysf.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!54FF19028BDE00EA!440.entry